jquery/fileUploader issue in magento after upgrading to Magento 2.4.7
If you're encountering this issue and unable to find a solution, try removing the following entry from your composer.json file
"blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader"

"blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader"
